# How to run selenium scripts in jenkins slave machine but the scripts are in Master machine

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have selenium scripts in my local system where jenkins is installed i want to run the scripts in slave machine without copying the selenium scripts in slave machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Selenium plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin) to transform your Jenkins environment into a Selenium Grid. If you do that you need to initialize your [`RemoteWebDriver`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver)s with the Jenkins master as the hub.